# sqoop import from vertica failed

Tags: sqoop, vertica, sqoop2, bigdata, database

I am trying to import dataset from Vertica to HDFS using sqoop2.

I a running following query on sqoop machines to import data into hdfs from Vertica v6.0.1-7

```
sqoop import -m 1 --driver com.vertica.jdbc.Driver --connect "jdbc:vertica://10.10.10.10:5433/MYDB" --password dbpassword --username dbusername --target-dir "/user/my/hdfs/dir" --verbose --query 'SELECT * FROM ORDER_V2 LIMIT 10;'
```

but i am getting some error here,

```
16/02/03 10:33:17 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: Query [SELECT * FROM ORDER_V2 LIMIT 10;] must contain '$CONDITIONS' in WHERE clause.
at org.apache.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.getColumnTypes(ConnManager.java:300)
at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnTypes(ClassWriter.java:1833)
at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1645)
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:96)
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:478)
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
```

Anyone knows how to do this, considering different username on both machines.

Comment: Did you read the manual? https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.1-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#_free_form_query_imports

Comment: I just figured out. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after adding vertica_5.1.4_jdk_5.jar to /var/lib/sqoop

and Addition of `WHERE $CONDITIONS` solved the issue

```
sqoop import -m 1 --driver com.vertica.jdbc.Driver --connect "jdbc:vertica://10.10.10.10:5433/MYDB" --password dbpassword --username dbusername --target-dir "/user/my/hdfs/dir" --verbose --query 'SELECT * FROM ORDER_V2 WHERE $CONDITIONS;'
```