# Sqoop2 import from Vertica v6.0.1-7

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, vertica, sqoop2

I am trying to import Vertica data into Hadoop/Hive/Impala.
I am Vertica v6.0.1-7 & CDH 5.4. I have Sqoop 1.99.5-cdh5.4.0 (sqoop2) installed through CM.

I tried to create link using following command

```
sqoop:000> create link --cid 4
Creating link for connector with id 4
Please fill following values to create new link object
Name: vertica

Link configuration

JDBC Driver Class: com.vertica.jdbc.Driver
JDBC Connection String: jdbc:vertica://10.1.1.1:5433/PROD
Username: user
Password: *******
JDBC Connection Properties:
There are currently 0 values in the map:
entry#
```

after this it got stuck here if I hit enter it start over again.

any idea how do I create this import using sqoop2.

also anyone know if I can just do this import in one command line the way sqoop1 does.

thanks

Comment: Was this not resolved in your [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35206894/sqoop-import-from-vertica-failed)?

Comment: It was complaining Could not load db driver class: com.vertica.jdbc.Driver. Then i realize /var/lib/sqoop is empty, so now trying to use sqoop2. now at least /var/lib/sqoop2/ has jar file.